# How to archive hive tables?

Tags: unix, hive

Is there a way to check hive external tables which are created 90 days before and drop those tables along with underlying hdfs data.  Can this be achieved in unix script?

Comment: Of course we can implement this by a shell script, you can execute `hadoop fs -ls /path/your_hive_table_path/` to get the data written time, and then execute the `hadoop fs -rm ` to remove the data which has been created over 90 days.

Comment: I would need to drop the table as well how that can be done

Comment: Well, add a code to execute HiveQL `drop table`.

Comment: Can you help how can i able to do that

Comment: OK. I will give you some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, if the hive tables path is `/path/your_hive_table_path/` as below:

```
hadoop --cluster your-hadoop-cluster fs -ls /path/your_hive_table_path/

drwxrwxrwx+  - h_mifi supergroup          0 2019-01-24 10:33 /path/your_hive_table_path//mifidw_car_insurance_expire_month_data
drwxrwxrwx+  - h_mifi supergroup          0 2019-01-24 10:39 /path/your_hive_table_path//mifidw_car_owner
drwxr-xr-x+  - h_mifi supergroup          0 2019-05-30 03:01 /path/your_hive_table_path//push_credit_card_mine_result_new
drwxr-xr-x+  - h_mifi supergroup          0 2019-05-30 03:41 /path/your_hive_table_path//push_live_payment_bill_mine_result_new
```

We can get the table file lastest updated date as below:

```
hadoop --cluster your-hadoop-cluster fs -ls /path/your_hive_table_path/ | awk -F'[ ]+' '{print $6}'
2019-01-24
2019-01-24
2019-05-30
2019-05-30
```

We need a `loop` to check every table whether is over 90 days and to execute `remove` and `drop` operations. The complete shell script is below, I have tested, it worked well, hope it would help for you.

```
hadoop --cluster your-hadoop-cluster fs -ls /path/your_hive_table_path/ | grep '/path/your_hive_table_path/' | while read line
do
   #Get the update date of hive table
   date_str=`echo $line | awk -F'[ ]+' '{print $6}'`
   #get the path of hive table
   table_path=`echo $line | awk -F'[ ]+' '{print $8}'`
   #Get the table name of hive table
   table_name=`echo $table_path | awk -F'/' '{print $7}' `

   today_date_stamp=`date +%s`
   table_date_stamp=`date -d $date_str +%s`
   stamp_diff=`expr $today_date_stamp - $table_date_stamp`

   #Get the diff days from now
   days_diff=`expr $stamp_diff / 86400`

   #if diff days is greater than 90, rm and drop.
   if [ $days_diff -gt 90 ];then
      #remove the hdfs file
      hadoop --cluster your-hadoop-cluster fs -rm $table_path
      #drop the hive table
      hive -e"drop table $table_name"
   fi
done
```

Comment: I think best way is to change the property file to internal and drop the table. Will that be a good idea

Comment: Yeah, it is a way to implement this too, but if you don't want to change everything about your table, you can just execute the script above. And you can set a `crontab` scheduler for the script to check and drop the expired tables every day.

Comment: Just be carefully, we maintain our hive data warehouse with the `shell script` in our routine work, and it's convenient.

Comment: If it is convenient for you, give me a `vote up` please, since I have spent more than half an hour to edit this answer in the morning of this working day.Thanks very much ! :) .